# Where is |DataDirectory| defined?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, vwdexpress

This is a follow up question of [Where is that file on my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169590/)

Tons of questions and answers all over SO and the internet but I can't find any that gives an answer to this specific question.

All is default but I can't find the file itself,

### **IT'S NOT THERE**.

Where/**how** gets |DataDirectory| **defined**?

Where is the file saved, does it even exist? If not, what is going on?

**edit**: The file **isn't** located at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();` all (sqattered) answers tell me it should be. It must be somewhere as the debugger breaks nagging about the model unequals the table when I change the model. It's **not** there.

Answer (score 75):

The `|DataDirectory|` isn't a file per se. A quote from a rather old MSDN article:

> By default, the **|DataDirectory|** variable will be expanded as follow:
>
> - For applications placed in a directory on the user machine, this will be the app's (.exe) folder.
> - For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder created by ClickOnce
> - For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder
>
> Under the hood, the value for **|DataDirectory|** simply comes from a property on the app domain. It is possible to change that value and override the default behavior by doing this:
>
> ```
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newpath)
> ```

A further quote regarding your schema inconsistencies:

> One of the things to know when working with local database files is that they are treated as any other content files. For desktop projects, it means that by default, the database file will be copied to the output folder (aka bin) each time the project is built. After F5, here's what it would look like on disk
>
> ```
>  MyProject\Data.mdf
>
>  MyProject\MyApp.vb
>
>  MyProject\Bin\Debug\Data.mdf
>
>  MyProject\Bin\Debug\MyApp.exe
> ```
>
> At design-time, MyProject\Data.mdf is used by the data tools. At run-time, the app will be using the database under the output folder. As a result of the copy, many people have the impression that the app did not save the data to the database file. In fact, this is simply because there are two copies of the data file involved. Same applies when looking at the schema/data through the database explorer. The tools are using the copy in the project, not the one in the bin folder.

Comment: Was half way through typing the answer when your answer came in. Well researched!

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") returns NULL

Answer (score 19):

The |datadirectory| algorithm is located in the System.Data.dll assembly, in the internal System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions class. Here it as displayed by [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) (note the source it's now available in the reference source repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/e458f8df6ded689323d4bd1a2a725ad32668aaec/System.Data.Entity/System/Data/EntityClient/DbConnectionOptions.cs):

```cs
internal static string ExpandDataDirectory(string keyword,
                                           string value,
                                           ref string datadir)
{
    string text = null;
    if (value != null && 
        value.StartsWith("|datadirectory|", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string text2 = datadir;
        if (text2 == null)
        {
            // 1st step!
            object data = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
            text2 = (data as string);
            if (data != null && text2 == null)
                throw ADP.InvalidDataDirectory();

            if (ADP.IsEmpty(text2))
            {
                // 2nd step!
                text2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            }
            if (text2 == null)
            {
                text2 = "";
            }
            datadir = text2;
        }

        // 3rd step, checks and normalize
        int length = "|datadirectory|".Length;
        bool flag = 0 < text2.Length && text2[text2.Length - 1] == '\\';
        bool flag2 = length < value.Length && value[length] == '\\';
        if (!flag && !flag2)
        {
            text = text2 + '\\' + value.Substring(length);
        }
        else
        {
            if (flag && flag2)
            {
                text = text2 + value.Substring(length + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                text = text2 + value.Substring(length);
            }
        }
        if (!ADP.GetFullPath(text).StartsWith(text2, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            throw ADP.InvalidConnectionOptionValue(keyword);
    }
    return text;
}
```

So it looks in the current AppDomain data first (by default, there is no "DataDirectory" data defined I believe) and then gets to the current AppDomain base directory. The rest is mostly checks for path roots and paths normalization.

Answer (score 2):

On the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/) there is a similiar but simplified question about this, which says:

By default the |DataDirectory| points to your application folder (as you figured out yourself in the original question: to the App_Data).

Since is just a substitution path to your database, you can define the path yourself with the **AppDomain.SetData**.

Comment: Tons of questions and answers all over SO and the internet but I can't find any that gives an answer to this specific question.