# Get Absolute Path to App_Data From Job

Tags: c#, jobs, quartz.net, worker, appdata

I have a class, `EmailSendJob`, that implements `IJob` and I need to get the path to the `App_Data` folder in my web project from the `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` method of the `EmailSendJob` class. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is |DataDirectory| defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined)

Comment: Do you schedule this EmailSendJob from the web project?

Answer (score 1):

Probably want something like:

```
var appDataPath = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
```

(should work for ASP.Net or Local Applications)