# Error using Data Source relative path in Excel Data Driven Unit Test

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, odbc

I am using a System.Data.Odbc connection string to connect to an Excel data source. The following error occurs when using a relative **dbq** path:

> ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

App.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="excelConnection" connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;Dbq=ExcelDataSource.xlsx;Defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
        <dataSources>
            <add name="excelDataSource" connectionString="excelConnection" dataTableName="Sheet1$" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
        </dataSources>
    </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
</configuration>
```

Test Method Attributes:

```
[DeploymentItem("ExcelDataSource.xlsx")]
[DataSource("excelDataSource")]
[TestMethod]
```

Troubleshooting notes:

- Works with an absolute **dbq** path
- Excel file is set to 'Copy if Newer' and [DeploymentItem] is specified
- Fails before reaching the [TestInitialize] method; before the Test Deployment Dir is created.
- It worked in the past, perhaps in an older Visual Studio version

**Question: Where does defaultDir=.; resolve to?**

Comment: What is the name of the first worksheet ?

Comment: Actual sheets names: "Full", "Lite". I'm trying to access "Full".

Comment: Is dataTableName set to "Full$"?

Comment: Did you change the error message as well then ?

Comment: Yes, I substituted 'Full' with 'Sheet1' to be more generic. As I said it works with an absolute path so the names appear correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It resolved correctly using |DataDirectory| variable: defaultDir=|DataDirectory|.

```
connectionString="Dsn=Excel Files;Dbq=ExcelDataSource.xlsx;Defaultdir=|datadirectory|\;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5"
```

[More on the |DataDirectory| variable here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined)