# Chart control won't populate due to invalid path

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I can't populate my chart control due to invalid path exception, yet all my Database paths are correct in both **App.Config** and **Settings.Designer.cs**, the database is located in *Bin\Debug\DB\Access.accdb*.

App.Config:

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB\maindb.accdb"
```

Settings.Designer.cs:

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\DB\\maindb.accdb")]
```

This is the path given in the error:
[image]

Comment: What's the correct path? And what is the output folder of your project?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten correct path is `C:\Users\Omar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Inventory And Costumer Manager\Inventory And Costumer Manager\bin\Debug\DB\maindb.accdb`, output as in Debug or Release ?

Comment: In this case, you need to remove |DataDirectory| from the connection string.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten ...that will just make the stuff more troublesome, also it doesn't work, it just makes the path `C:\DB\maindb.accdb`

Comment: Where is the exe file located? Just right on C:?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten `C:\Users\Omar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Inventory And Costumer Manager\Inventory And Costumer Manager\bin\Debug\`

Comment: connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DB\maindb.accdb" Try like this.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten Nope, same result, empty chart.

Comment: Are you manually setting the "DataDirectory" variable to a custom path as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined ?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten i do not remember doing so, and there is no trace of it in the form's code neither in the whole project.