# Database '<db_name>' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, localdb

I'm using VS 2015 and Entity Framework 6.0. I'm working on Windows Forms application that uses Entity Framework as a database access layer.
I have my database in .MDF file. 
When I'm trying to regenerate database with `Generate database from model...` after making some changes in `EDMX diagram` everything works fine but at the end when trying to execute SQL DDL script I get: `Database '<db_name>' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

Here is the connection string:

  `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataInFileEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainAppModel.csdl|res://*/MainAppModel.ssdl|res://*/MainAppModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\WinFormsAppDb.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Moreover I can connect to the database with built-in `Server Explorer` and `SQL Server Object Explorer`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database? For executables, `|DataDirectory|` points to the same folder as the exe. When debugging, that's `bin\debug`

Comment: Check this possible duplicate, [Where is DatDirectory defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined)

Comment: I'm not debugging. I just recreating tables after changes in EDMX diagram.

Comment: 'bin\debug' is directory where db is copied to run application. I do not run application

Comment: How? Where is your executable? If you run in debug mode, it's in `bin\debug`. If you run in release mode, it's in `bin\release`. Did you encounter the problem after deploying to `Program Files` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  
I'm not debugging. I just recreating tables after changes in EDMX diagram.

Comment: .MDF file is in data dir. I do not run debugger or application. I just recreating db after changes in EDMX diagram

Comment: How are you recreating it? What command line did you use? What script? Without the relevant information one can only guess

Comment: When I'm trying to regenerate database with `Generate database from model...` (right click in EDMX) after making some changes in `EDMX diagram` like in the question states

Comment: This question is specific for EF6 and Model First approach. EF6 generates sql which is supposed to create/update db and it just fails to run in standard scenario. Looks like bug in EF connection string generator. This is not question about proper location of db files.