# Access database error “Could not find file”

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I run my program in Visual Studio, The message pops up, The file name and the file name in the Visual Basic is the same `SUPPLIER_QUOTATION`.

I already tried renaming the file but did not seems to work.

```vb
Public Sub connection()
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "SUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb"
        .Open()
    End With
End Sub
```

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Patrick Echenique\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2012\Projects\SUPPLIER QUOTATION\SUPPLIER QUOTATION\bin\DebugSUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb'.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a backslash`\`in front of filename!

Path should be:

> C:\Users\Patrick Echenique\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SUPPLIER QUOTATION\SUPPLIER QUOTATION\bin\Debug\SUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb

Change code to:

```
.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                    Application.StartupPath & "\SUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb"
```

UPDATE (suggested by @Jimi):

```vb
.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb"
```

I am not sure about the benefits of [|DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined/12276625#12276625), but I am a novice in VB.Net.

Comment: `.ConnectionString = "(...);Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SUPPLIER_QUOTATION.mdb"`

Comment: The use of [|DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276625/7444103) instead of `Application.StartupPath`.

Comment: No need for me to edit your answer. You already provided an example and a link, which includes the definition and specify its usage. Future readers may find your answer more useful this way.

Comment: This is a common feature, not related to a specific language. It comes from `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions `

Comment: Common for .Net. But not on VBA ;(. As a compensation, Ms Access has SubForms (and I won't swap them for .Net) :D