# Sqlite - No such table exists, even though it exists?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hiyya,

We're currently working on a project where we need to locally store data (configuration data, more specifically) and figured Sqlite is a decent solution for now.

However, after setting up the DBContext, Entities and whatnot, creating a migration and running `Update-Database` to create the database (and confirming through `DB Browser for SQLite` that it "properly" created it), we are met with a "No such table found" error.

**DataService.cs**

```
private SettingsModel GetConfig()
    {
        using(var _context = new DataContext())
        {
            var query = (from a in _context.SettingsModel
                         select a);

            var obj = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.ExpressionString))
                obj.ExpressionString = DEFAULT_EXPRESSION_STRING;

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

**DbContext.cs**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<SettingsModel> SettingsModel { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data source=keyconfig.db");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SettingsModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();
            entity.Property(e => e.ExpressionString)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
    }
}
```

**SettingsModel.cs**

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public string ExpressionString { get; set; }
}
```

I am honestly quite dumb-founded why this is not working (or why we're having the issue we're having), especially after confirming the database and it's table(s) *does* exist, so any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the database is created where the running application looks for it?

Comment: Examine `_context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString`, does it point to the existing database containing the table?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for bringing attention to that! Apparently it's not happy over the fact that the table has no primary key, which also makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually, it would seem I was a bit too optimistic. The error remains. As for the connection string, that is simply what you see in the snippet above (`optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(...)`). Perhaps some kind of absolute bath is required?

Comment: @IvanStoev Okay, much like I suspected it would seem we need a absolute path given (for now)

Comment: @Xariez Eventually you can try utilizing `|DataDirectory|` as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#data-source), although it's not quite clear how it works - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276625/5202563. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again! If you post something as an actual "answer", I'll mark it as such as well! :) @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary fix was to use an absolute path to the .SQLITE database, instead of a relative one. Will be looked into/troubleshooted again later.