# How to make a dynamic route in app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

How can I make a dynamic route in app.config on C#. Because this project will run on multiple machines.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RutaEvidencias" 
         value="D://Users/WA5699CR/OneDrive - GrupoMonge/Desktop/Evidencias/"/>   
</appSettings>
```

But I need to do it dynamic

Comment: [Try to use |DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined).

Comment: How can I know the [DataDirectory] of my project? Because I tried and its work, but I don´t know the route