# Deploy C# Application With Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

I want to deploy the C# application with the MS Access database("I want to give Path for database"),
so I can go to the client and install the application with the database will save at given Path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, are you asking how to create an installer which will deploy the application and database?

Comment: This is what [|DataDirectory|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined) is for; don't fix the path

Comment: I want give path for database, so that when i install Application, database should placed at given path.