# vb2022 vb.net .net6 vb complie error exit with error code error when looking for my bd

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, installation, path

I am working in Visual Basic 2022 making a database for a doctor's office, but when I package and create a Setup the address of my computer is saved in the path of the access database and when I run my application it says the following " C:\User\project\patients.accdb is not a valid path, how can I correct this, thanks for your help

modificated this property

or I don't know if I'm doing the Setup wrong

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0),  [Where is |DataDirectory| defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined), and [ADO.NET |DataDirectory| where is this documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented/1409378#1409378)

Comment: You could also get the current running folder when you applicaiton is launched, and thus use the path name from the .exe file on startup. That would thus allow your application and connection string to work regardless as to where the .exe file and the database are placed. it not clear if you place the database (accdb file) in the same folder as the .exe file, but on startup, it is a simple matter to get the current folder location, and thus use that for the connection string path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying the database with the application, the proper way to go about this is to add the data file to the project and set its `Copy to output directory` to `Copy if newer`, then use `"|DataDirectory|"` in your connection string as the folder path. That will automatically resolve to the correct folder no matter where the application is deployed as well as when running in the debugger. See [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for some examples.

Note that, for most deployed applications, the data directory defaults to the program folder. This means that the advice above is like using `Application.StartupPath` in a WinForms app but you don't have to use code to set it. If you use ClickOnce deployment then the data directory is managed by ClickOnce and the connection string is resolved automatically still. For Web Forms apps, it resolves to the App_Data folder. Not sure what happens for more modern web apps as I've never tried it.

Comment: thanks friend I will see the examples and comment the results...

Comment: hello again jmcilhinney this DataDirectory function now my application finds the access file but I don't understand why it only allows me to search but not enter or update records, it already changes the privileges of the db file but it still doesn't let me make modifications. any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: The comments on an answer is not the place to ask new questions. This answer has addressed the question you actually asked so you should accept it. If you now have a new question then you should post it as a new question, containing all and only the relevant information for that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the connection ODBC rather than native.
That would remove the need to manage the physical path to the database. It would also provide more flexibility and cater to future needs such as upgrading the database (for example, from MS Access to SQL Server).

Comment: No, even when using ODBC to ms-access, the connection sting will ALWAYS have a full valid windows path name to the database file. The path name used can't even be relative, it has to be a fully qualified windows path. While a connections to server database can use IP address, Access is file based and even odbc requires a valid windows path name to the database file. I MOST certainly agree with your suggestion to use the ODBC provider in place of say the VERY common oleDB provide since that allows a simple connection string change without having to change the data provider for SQL server

Comment: Albert, I believe you are referring to DSN-less ODBC connection string. If the machine has an ODBC DSN for the database, the connection string can be as simple as myConnectionString = "DSN=myDSN;"

Comment: Well, it can be a DSN less, but the DSN NOW has a full qualified windows path name. In other words, the conneciton string at the end of the day must and still has a full valid path name to the database file. Introduction of ODBC does not change this issue or requirement. Given that this is .net, then using oleDB provider, or ODBC provider? Why not make the connection string in the application. So, creating  or even having to create an entry in the ODBC panel? I don't see any advantages as such. And still in ALL cases, a valid path name exists.

Comment: I see VERY little reason to make or require or to use ANY connection that has to be entered in the registiry (machine DSN), or into a file (a FILE dsn). Since a full path name to the database is required in all cases, then introduction of a DSN into registry, or a file is really not required.  In fact in most cases, in .net we don't create nor use a FILE or system DSN, but use the connection builder in Visual Studio, and thus once again, even less reason exists to consider using DSN's,  and .net by default does not require nor use them anyway.

Comment: The reason is flexibility (decoupling), which is a key feature of ODBC DSNs. You may prefer managing the physical (rather than logical) aspects of data source connection inside the application. But it is perfectly viable to delegate the physical aspects to an ODBC DSN and retain only the logical aspects inside the application.

Comment: Sure- your 100% correct.  Machines are often so locked down I don't like dsn's a lot,  but that changes little in your valid points.  And in theory a change in connection becomes external.